# Filter child datatable based on parent datatable with ForeignKeyConstraint

Tags: vb.net

I have a stored procedure in SQL server that return two tables to my VB.Net form. These two tables fills two grids. My data tables are parent and child. I want to filter second grid by first grid. In other words when user select one record in first grid, second grid must be filtered by regarding primary key that declared programmatically. 
But it doesn't work!
My Code likes this:

```
Dim DAContractorDateTreeView As New SqlDataAdapter("spTimeSheetReportDateTree", My.Settings.SyncConnectionString)
Dim DSContractorDate As New DataSet
Dim fkeyConstraint As ForeignKeyConstraint
Dim Binding1, Binding2 As New BindingSource

Sub LoadContractorsDate(MyParameter As Integer)
    Try
      DAContractorDateTreeView.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
      'Some Codes for adding parameters
      DAContractorDateTreeView.Fill(DSContractorDate)

      'Declare parent column and child column variables.
      Dim ParentColumn, ChildColumn As DataColumn
      Dim primaryKey(1) As DataColumn
      primaryKey(0) = DSContractorDate.Tables(2).Columns("TiSheID")
      DSContractorDate.Tables(2).PrimaryKey = primaryKey

      'Set parent and child column variables.
      ParentColumn = DSContractorDate.Tables(0).Columns("TiSheID")
      ChildColumn = DSContractorDate.Tables(1).Columns("TiSheID")
      fkeyConstraint = New ForeignKeyConstraint("FKConstraintNaID", ParentColumn, ChildColumn)

      'Set null values when a value is deleted.
      fkeyConstraint.DeleteRule = Rule.Cascade
      fkeyConstraint.UpdateRule = Rule.Cascade
      fkeyConstraint.AcceptRejectRule = AcceptRejectRule.Cascade

      'Add the constraint, and set EnforceConstraints to true.
      DSContractorDate.Tables(1).Constraints.Add(fkeyConstraint)

      DSContractorDate.EnforceConstraints = True

      Binding1.DataSource = DSContractorDate.Tables.Item(0)
      GridControlExit.DataSource = Binding1
      Binding1.DataMember = "TiSheID"

      Binding2.DataMember = "FKConstraintNaID" 'fkeyConstraint.ConstraintName
      MsgBox(fkeyConstraint.ConstraintName)
      Binding2.DataSource = Binding1
      GridControlDetail.DataSource = Binding2

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I haven't any problem with loading data from stored procedure.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might well have found a solution for this now but the Microsoft intended it to be is:

- add a new DataSet to your project
- Open it and right click the surface
- Add a tableadapter for `select * from parent`
- do the same for the child. If the database contains a foreign key then a datarelation will be created automatically. If it is not, Highlight the column in the parent that links to the child then drag a line from the grey square next to the column name and drop it on the related child column name, ensure the datarelation window settings are correct
- save the DataSet and go to your form
- open the DataSources window (view menu, other windows) and expand every node and look at it. You'll see two children, one under the parent and one not
  *drop all three of these grid on your form, run the app

You'll notice that for the grid under the parent, when you select a parent the child grid filters automatically. If you stop the app and examine the datasources of the child grids you'll see why. Both grids have datasources that are bindingsources but for the grid that filters automatically, the relevant bindingsource has its DataSource set to be the parent bindingsource and it's DataMember is the name of the datarelation

You can probably replicate the same into your manual code there but give a thought to starting working with datasets and tableadapters; they make a lot of the code you're writing now easier and more functional.

Final point; when configuring your adapters you made the queries "select * from table". In production you wouldn't do this; don't download all the table data and filter on the child. Add multiple relevant queries to your tableadapters and use them; `select * from users where lastname like @ln` And call it fillbylastname, if you want wildcards put them in the code: `usersTableAdapter.FillByLastName(appDataSet.Users, "Smi%")`